# Automagically generating notebooks with collapsed sections

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, creation

The code block below

```
CreateDocument[{
  TextCell["Title", "Title"],
  TextCell["Subtitle", "Subtitle"],
  TextCell["Section 1", "Section"],
  TextCell["Section 1.1", "Subsection"],
  TextCell["Section 1.2", "Subsection"],
  TextCell["Section 1.3", "Subsection"],
  TextCell["Section 2", "Section"],
  TextCell["Section 2.1", "Subsection"],
  TextCell["Section 2.2", "Subsection"],
  TextCell["Section 2.3", "Subsection"],
  TextCell["Section 3", "Section"],
  TextCell["Section 2.1", "Subsection"],
  TextCell["Section 2.2", "Subsection"],
  TextCell["Section 2.3", "Subsection"]}
 ]
```

will create a skeleton notebook.

Is it possible to create that notebook so that the sections are collapsed? So that the notebook will be displayed as if (eg) the Cell closer covering Section 1 had been clicked. Ditto for Sections 2 & 3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use CellGroup to open or close specific cells - see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellGroup.html

```
CreateDocument[{
  TextCell["Title", "Title"],
  TextCell["Subtitle", "Subtitle"],
  CellGroup[{
    TextCell["Section 1", "Section"],
    TextCell["Section 1.1", "Subsection"], 
    TextCell["Section 1.2", "Subsection"], 
    TextCell["Section 1.3", "Subsection"]
  }, Closed],
  TextCell["Section 2", "Section"],
  TextCell["Section 2.1", "Subsection"], 
  TextCell["Section 2.2", "Subsection"], 
  TextCell["Section 2.3", "Subsection"],
  TextCell["Section 3", "Section"],
  TextCell["Section 2.1", "Subsection"], 
  TextCell["Section 2.2", "Subsection"], 
  TextCell["Section 2.3", "Subsection"]}]
```

Or you could wrap the entire collection of TextCells in one high-level CellGroup and play with CellGroup's optional second argument.  For example, this will open only the first three cell groups:

```
CreateDocument[{
  CellGroup[{
    TextCell["Title", "Title"],
    TextCell["Subtitle", "Subtitle"],
    TextCell["Section 1", "Section"],
    TextCell["Section 1.1", "Subsection"], 
    TextCell["Section 1.2", "Subsection"], 
    TextCell["Section 1.3", "Subsection"],
    TextCell["Section 2", "Section"],
    TextCell["Section 2.1", "Subsection"], 
    TextCell["Section 2.2", "Subsection"], 
    TextCell["Section 2.3", "Subsection"],
    TextCell["Section 3", "Section"],
    TextCell["Section 2.1", "Subsection"], 
    TextCell["Section 2.2", "Subsection"], 
    TextCell["Section 2.3", "Subsection"]
  }, {1, 2, 3}]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Bill White!  The first example was just what I was after.

Comment: And thank you for accepting my answer.  By the way, using Closed as CellGroup's second argument seems to be undocumented, unless I'm overlooking something.  I use CellGroupData[{...}, Closed] all the time when generating notebooks programmatically, and Closed seems to work fine here, too.